# How to make a nav-item with bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation, nav

So I've got this problem, that i have everthing working as I want it to, but I can't figure out how I make the text "Profil" look like the standard Bootstrap nav-item? see "Zahlungen" for reference.

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mainStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigationbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../Zahlungsuebersicht/Zahlungsuebersicht.jsp">Zahlungen <i class="fas fa-receipt"></i></a>
      </li>
      <!-- Profil -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-link">
          <a href="#yourlink">Profil </a>
          <i class="fas fa-user dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop2" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#bearbeiten">Profil bearbeiten <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#abmelden">Abmelden <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
          </div>
       </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you just want the link `Profil` to be the same colour, then simply add the class `nav-link` to your `<a>` tag.

Wrap the `<i>` tag in the anchor, so that clicking on your icon causes the dropdown as well.

**EDIT**: Keeping it all in the same line:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#yourlink">Profil 
    <i class="fas fa-user" href="#" id="navbardrop2" ></i>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#bearbeiten">Profil bearbeiten <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#abmelden">Abmelden <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
   </div>
</li>
```

It's currently inheriting the blue highlight colour from Bootstrap's default styles, but by adding the class to the tag it will apply the styles of the class to it.

By also adding the `dropdown-toggle` class and `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the `<a>` it will now trigger drop-down when clicking Profil

The arrow-down symbol will appear from Bootstrap's pseudo class :after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that, but when i do that, the dropdown moves under the text and it is no more only all in 1 line.

Comment: I've modifed my answer to suit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want it to be like two seperate elements, like you have the link on "Profil", then also have the dropdown on the right hand side.
Is there some other way I could get the css effects from bootstrap?
That's why I've added the `<span>` element, it works on the `<i>` element but doesn't work on the `<a>` element.

Comment: Split dropdown or Profil is entirely separate?

Because if it's separate you can just wrap the `<i>` in a new `<a>` to suit

Answer (score 0):

Must Use navlink class inside anchor tag.

`<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" class="nav-link">Profile</a>
</li>`